# After export, Runnable Jar File doesnt run

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, jogl, malformedurlexception

After exporting a game app I'm making as a runnable `.jar` file, I ran it from the command prompt only to find some issues. I've had to solve some issues with not finding audio path and not being able to read/write into `.txt` files. Audio I've looked and was able to solve, the files one I looked and came to close to solving it but after making a post here I learned all I was missing was a `.` at the start of my fileNames. Now there's only one problem left.

When I export it with:

> extract required libraries into JAR

it gives me this exception:

```
Catched FileNotFoundException .... -natives-windows-i586.jar(System couldnt locate especified file) ...

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedlinkError: Cant load library: ...\gluegen-rt.dll
```

When I export it with:

> package required libraries into generated JAR`

it says:

```
Catched MalformedURLException: Could not open Inputstream for URL: 'rsrc:glugen-rt-natives-windows-i586.jar', ....

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.invocationTargetException

Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedlinkError: Cant load library: ...\gluegen-rt.dll
```

The build path looks something like this:

> **Source:**  `CubeSurvivor/src`
>
> **Projects:** `JOGL` *(where `glugen-rt.dll` is and this project is required because it contains everything related to graphics)*
>
> **Libraries:** `JRE System Library[JavaSE-1.8]`
>
> **Order and Export:**
>
> - `CubeSurvivor/src` with box filled
> - `JRE System Library[JavaSE-1.8]` box not filled *(tried with box selected)*
> - `JOGL` box not filled *(tried with box selected)*

I dont understand what I'm doing wrong, from the looks of it, it seems maybe the project containing `JOGL` isn't going to the `.jar` file but I've confirmed that it is while opening with `7-zip` but I couldn't find `gluegen-rt.dll` (maybe haven't looked well enough its thousands upon thousands of files). That file along with other `.jar` files are located inside a folder on `JOGL`.

Maybe this file isn't being copied or extracted to the `.jar` file created?

Or is there something wrong with my build path? If so, what should I do?

Should I add all the files inside `JOGL` to the `src`?

Edit:

I extracted the jar file with 7-zip to run a file search, I made random searches(after all its thousands of files) and all except those in a folder called lib, JOGL.iml and referenced libraries, all inside JOGL, were not found, the folder itself was not found. Everything else was.

Heres what the inside of JOGL looks like:

[JOGL Project View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCNQ7.png)

lib, JOGL.iml and referenced libraries are not in the jar file aparently.

Comment: You were given an error message about missing the natives jar. Are you sure that it's included?

Comment: There is a folder inside jogl called lib where glegen-rt.jar is located and that folder i cant find it after export on the jar file, Im able to find thousands of files from JOGL but that folder and files i dont seem to find them. Might i add JOGl project has that folder lib(where glugen-rt.jar / glugen.jar / jogl-all.jar are located), a zip with all docs called jogl-all-docs.zip, a file called JOGL.iml and in referenced libraries(gluegen-rt.jar and jogl-all.jar). lib is not a src folder its a regular folder, does that have anyhting to do with this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know Eclipse. Does your project run in Eclipse? Did you clone jogl and added it as dependency?

Comment: Works perfectly on Eclipse. As for the jogl project, after downloading it I imported it to my workspace using <import / Existing Projects into Workspace> and after that, i made my game project, its build path is as shown on the post.

Comment: I advise you to use jogamp-fat.jar instead of all separate JARs and to merge your own JAR with it. I advise you to read our wiki carefully before asking questions about JOGL on StackOverflow: http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/JogAmp_JAR_File_Handling#Eclipse If you don't respect our native library layout, the native libraries won't be found by GlueGen, won't be extracted and won't be found by Java itself.

Comment: If you want a better control on the fat JAR creation, rather use Ant.

Comment: Ive done everything it says in the link you provided http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/JogAmp_JAR_File_Handling#Eclipse, but after doing exactly what they say, my program wont run anymore on eclipse and throws an "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cant load library: ... \gluegen-rt.dll . On one hand you were right i wasnt using it the recommended way(wasnt aware) but on the other why cant it run even on eclipse now?

Comment: Ok its running on eclipse, i was adding JOGL to the user libraries with the system library checked, i unchecked it and saw that it was working again on eclipse. I then exported again as extract required libraries..., tested didnt work, after i did the same as package required libraries... and it WORKED!! I mean, there might be new bugs im unaware but as of now its finally able to run without eclipse. So i just wanted to say, thank you, and sorry for the inconvenience. I'll be sure to head those advises so i dont make the same mistake in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so this thread has been resolved, the answers are in the comments, so if anyone encounters a similar issue be sure to check it. I dont know how to make this thread end, im sure a moderator will see it.

So, i just wanted to say thank you all for your precious help and sorry after all it was my mistake not using JOGL properly. This link might help others in the future so im posting it here.

http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/JogAmp_JAR_File_Handling#Eclipse